# this.state.users.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6

Intentando mostrar datos en una vista en `React Js`, me he encontrado con un error que siguiendo los pasos del tutorial aun sigue persistiendo:

> this.state.users.map is not a function

El código es el siguiente

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import request from 'superagent';

class App extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            users: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        request.get('http://localhost:8080/api/usuarios')
        .end((err, res) => {
            const usuariosGet = JSON.parse(res.text).usuarios;
            this.setState({
                users: usuariosGet
            });
        });
    }

    render(){

        var mostrarUsuarios = this.state.users.map((usuario, i) => {
            return (<li key={i}>{usuario}</li>);
        });

        return(
            <div>                
                <h1>Hola Mundo React JS</h1>
                <ul>
                    {mostrarUsuarios}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )       
    }
}

export default App;
```

[image: results]

Comment: Y qué hay en `usuariosGet`? A lo mejor es un objeto y no un array

Comment: ya coloco como queda de esa forma, un segundo

Comment: @amenadiel asi queda, ```Array(2)0: Nombre: "Juan"__proto__: Object1: Nombre: "Isaac"__proto__: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array(0)```

Comment: Probablemente render se ejecuta antes de que tengas datos, intentando invocar `map` en un string vacio. Prueba iniciandolo en `[]`

Comment: @Klaimmore podrias revisar ahora que puse la imagen?

Comment: Al parecer no puedes usar un object entre llaves `{}` intenta ser explicito en como renderizar el objeto usuario como `{usuario.Nombre}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando se monta el componente `users` no es un array sino una cadena. Cuando se llama a `render()` por primera vez intentará ejecutar un `map` pero, dado que los strings no contienen tal método, fallará. La solución debe bastar con cambiar tu declaración en el constructor:

```
this.state = {
    users: []
};
```

---

**EDIT**

Respecto al error que mencionas en el comentario, se debe a que lo que recibes está estructurado así:

```
[
    { Nombre: 'Juan' },
    { Nombre: 'Isaac' }
]
```

Es un arreglo de *objetos* con una propiedad `Nombre`. El error es que no puedes renderizar objetos así como así, debes seleccionar alguna de sus propiedades:

```
var mostrarUsuarios = this.state.users.map((usuario, i) => {
    return (<li key={i}>{usuario.Nombre}</li>);
});
```

Comment: ahora me dice esto, ```Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Nombre}).```

Comment: ¿Cómo es la respuesta del servidor cuando haces la petición?

Comment: Y edito la prgunta espera

Comment: Puedes revisar ahora que esta la imagen?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales con gusto, ya actualicé mi respuesta. Gracias por la marca!

Comment: Gracias, eso hice ya con antelación, cuando me salio lo de `Nombre`, asumí que debía agregar el atributo.

Answer (score 2):

Me pasa lo mismo:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  state = {

    empresas:[]

  }

  componentDidMount () { 

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/empresas.json')
    .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
    .then(empresas => this.setState({empresas}))

  }

  render(){

    return (

      <div>
        <h1>Mi select</h1>
        <ul>
          {this.state.empresas.map(empresa => (
            <li key={empresa.rut}>
              {empresa.razonsocial}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>

    )

  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: Es confuso el texto que compaña tu código, ¿esto es una respuesta o un comentario indicando que *enfrentas el mismo error*?

Answer (score 1):

Consulta:

Tiene que llamarse `users:[]`

O puede llamarse de otra forma, ej. `empresas:[]`