# Como resuelvo el error .map is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

en esta oportunidad necesito de su ayuda, tengo una consulta  a la Bd de MongoDB y lo guardo en el estado de un componente.
Quiero mapearlo pero me arroja el error **.map is not a function.**
Pueden ayudarme por favor.
Aqui las imagenes.

[image: Pueden ver que creo un estate llamado tareas el cual recibira la consulta de la BD .. En la cobsoña del navegador muestra el array de objetos]

[image: aqui el codigo donde hago la consulta y el mapeo]

Y por ultimo el error:
[image: error]

Comment: Por favor, lo que se pueda poner como texto, como por ejemplo partes del código debe de ponerse de esa forma para facilitar la lectura y evitar de esta forma en la medida de lo posible los screenshots.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [this.state.users.map is not a function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140918/this-state-users-map-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras es el estado este es un array, por lo que no hay ningún problema con .map

```
const [tareas, setTareas ] = useState([])
```

Sin embargo, en la función consultarApi guardas las tareas como un objeto que solo tiene una propiedad tareas, en los objetos no existe la propiedad .map de ahí el error.

```
setTareas({ tareas: resultado })
```

Cómo el resultado retornada ya es un array en sí mismo podrías y deberías guardarlo de la siguiente manera y ya funcionaría el código:

```
setTareas(resultado)
```

La alternativa si lo quieres el estado con objetos es cuando realizas el map, primero llamar a la propiedad en cuestión del objeto que es el array:

```
tareas.tareas.map(...
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. Ese era el problema.

Comment: @FranzuaVelasquez si consideras que la respuesta fue de utilidad no olvides votar y aceptarla como válida, esto es de gran ayuda para toda la comunidad.